# How to obtain the GUID of an CRM Dynamics 2011 appointment stored in Outlook 2010?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, outlook-addin

I'd like to make a call to an appointment stored in Dynamics **but** displayed in Outlook.

Suppose that a user opens a window with said appointment (let's say "call mom"). I've added a button to the ribbon and I'd like it to cause a gender switch upon a click. If the user hits the button, I'd like to

1. update the appointment to be "call dad", instead, and
2. update some fields that aren't represented in Outlook.

The first part, I think is solvable by changing the text in the open window and allowing the user to store the new, dad-friendly value the usual way - by saving while closing the frame.

However, the second part, needs to be done "under the hood", since there might be no part of Outlook client window that contains value of the corresponding field in CRM Dynamics. As far I can see, I need to create a connection directly to CRM server and write to the field there **but** I'm not sure how to get the GUID of that certain appointment in order to refer to it on CRM server.

EDIT:

A clarification is needed. The action described will be performed **while inside the extra, open frame in Outlook** for the regarded appointment. If user double clicks an appointment in the calendar, a window pops out carrying all the info about it. In **that** window, I need to refer to the **currently opened/edited** appointment and obtain **its** GUID for CRM reference. My apologies if it wasn't as clear "on paper" as in my head. :)

Comment: When the user double double clicks the appointment in the Outlook calendar, is that appointment already tracked in the CRM?

Comment: @PeterMajeed What is "double double click"? Typo? However, you raise a valid point. If the OP tries to do something CRM related with an appointment that hasn't been CRM-tracked (or has been CRM-untracked, for that matter), he's going to get a null pointer exception on `xxx.UserData["crmid"].Value`. It's a good practice to use `if(xxx.UserData["crmid"] != null) DoTheCrmMagic();´.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a complement to the reply by @PeterMajeed one can build up the code for accessing **all** windows as follows.

```
foreach (Outlook.Inspector inspector in this.Application.Inspectors)
{
  Outlook.AppointmentItem item 
    = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
  Outlook.UserProperty property = item.UserProperties["crmid"];
  String crmId = String.Empty;
  if (property != null)
    crmId = (String) item.UserProperties["crmid"].Value;
}
```

And if you're interested in the actual one that has triggered the event (based on the assumption that it's the active one), you can use the code below.

```
Outlook.Inspector inspector 
  = this.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem 
    as Outlook.Inspector;
```

Answer (score 2):

The unique CRM information is stored in Outlook items as custom `UserProperties`. If you iterate through the `UserProperties` for any tracked appointment, you'll find a property called `crmid`. Assuming you can find the appointment in interest, you can find the `GUID` as below:

```
var guid = Guid.Parse((string)appt.UserProperties["crmid"].Value);
```

Comment: I'll try that the first thing in the morning. However, a small cloud of worry has thorned up. Why "assuming you can find"? After all, the call will be made while the very appointment is open in an editable window. I can't imagine any reason for it not being findable. What **might** go wrong? A little heads up, please, Peter. :)

Comment: Heh, sorry about that. I didn't include the code that demonstrates how to access the programmatic reference to the Outlook appointment (assuming you're using VSTO). If you need help doing that, you probably should edit the question or make a new one, but a little testing should clear up these issues.

Comment: Edited as requested. At work in 60 minutes so I've got high hopes, hehe. Thanks!